# how to make a d3 chart wrapped in functions (for eventual scrollytelling implementation)

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, scroll, visualization

Apologies for the question's wording, I am relatively new to `javascript` and `d3` and am working backwards from [this chart](http://igor.gold.ac.uk/~afarg001/example/d3LineGraphv4.html) I made earlier and j vallandingham’s scroller [www.vallandingham.me/scroll_demo].

Eventually I want to make a scrollytelling webpage in the functionality of that scroller.

How do I make the same chart in such a way that the relevant functions can be called like in that scroller's sections.js?

I have tried in [this example] however the console stopped giving me any errors to help me..

This is what I've got at the moment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XCOWU2hBodPf07JqN0xk

Many thanks in advance for any help/advice!

sections.js: github..com/vlandham/scroll_demo/blob/gh-pages/js/scroller.js